# Trying to install MariaDB on Dokku

Tags: ssh, mariadb, dokku

I'm on my Server via ssh and trying to install MariaDB plugin for Dokku:

```
root@CHF:/var/lib/dokku/plugins# sudo git clone https://github.com/krisrang/dokku-mariadb mariadb

Cloning into 'mariadb'...
remote: Counting objects: 68, done.
remote: Total 68 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 68
Unpacking objects: 100% (68/68), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

root@CHF:/var/lib/dokku/plugins# sudo dokku plugins-install

2016/03/24 15:10:42 open /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/mariadb/plugin.toml: no such file or directory
2016/03/24 15:10:42 open /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/md-plugin/plugin.toml: no such file or directory
root@CHF:/var/lib/dokku/plugins#
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Its not installed, I can't create a database and tables..

I tried also this way:

> sudo dokku plugin:install https://github.com/Kloadut/dokku-md-plugin
>   --name mariadb

Comment: I got a similar error with the mongodb plugin: `open /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/mongodb-plugin/plugin.toml: no such file or directory` Were u able to solve it?

Comment: Solved it, I was able to uninstall the obsolete mongodb plugin using: `dokku plugin:remove mongodb-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of `ls -lha /var/lib/dokku/plugins/enabled`

> There are two directories inside /var/lib/dokku/plugins/ : available and enabled.
>   "available" contains every plugin that was installed and not yet uninstalled;
>   "enabled" contains all plugins that are being used. Each plugin that is being used is actually just a "shortcut" pointing to a another directory.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/statianzo/dokku-shoreman/issues/22#issuecomment-159848995)

If you see a plugin you deleted outside of dokku, remove it with `rm -r /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/pluginNameHere`

Answer (score 0):

Those two plugins are not compatible with the latest version of dokku.